# Help identifying a kanji

Tags: characters

Well, generic questions like these are found aplenty, so I apologise in advance. That being said, I've spent the last hour trying to find the kanji in the image below (sadly, to no avail).

[image: Toothpaste with Kanji]

Here is what I've tried so far, and my assumptions:

1. The first thing that occurred to me was to use a finder by radicals (like Jisho, for example). Based on my knowledge, I've tried using the radicals ⽊ and ⼧ but nothing came up that resembled the last part.
2. I've also tried to write it down (hard as it is on a pc), but nothing relevant came up either.
3. Finally, I've also tried looking at every 9-stroke kanji there is. Nothing came up.

At this point, I'm assuming that one of three things happened:

1. I misinterpreted one of the radicals
2. I don't know how to count anymore >.< (jokes aside, maybe I mistook a stroke for two or vice-versa)
3. The one I'm hoping it's most likely (for the sake of my pride and sanity), there is a digital variant of this kanji that looks quite different from this (possibly less common or handwritten) version.

It is bothering me quite much not being able to find this kanji, specially because it does not even seem to be that hard...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

柠 is the Simplified Chinese version of 檸, the first character of 檸檬 (lemon). It is not used in Japanese.

Comment: Damn, hadn't thought about that. Even worse, there is another one of these toothpastes that used 炭 for charcoal, so I didn't even consider that it might have been simplified Chinese. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jak Google Translate would have given you this as a candidate for your handwriting, but only if "Detect language" (or Chinese) is selected as the source language. It seems to be excluded if Japanese is selected.